# C# List<> - Inserir na base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma app que pega em informação de uma `TextBox`, insere numa lista `List<>` e depois mostra numa `CheckBoxList`.
Exemplo:

```
List<string> quantidade = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   quantidade.Add(TextBoxQuantidade.Text.ToString());
}
List<string> artigo = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   artigo.Add(TextBoxArtigo.Text.ToString());
}
List<string> valor = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
   valor.Add(TextBoxValor.Text.ToString());
}
/*List<string> artigo = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    artigo.Add(TextBoxArtigo.Text.ToString());
  }*/

CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Add(new ListItem("Quantidade: " + TextBoxQuantidade.Text + " Artigo: " + TextBoxArtigo.Text + " Valor: " + TextBoxValor.Text) + " Anexo: " + FileUpload1.FileName.ToString());
```

E eu quero adicionar à base de dados todas as linhas inseridas no `List<>` e ja tenho este exemplo:

```
SqlCommand sqlInsertList = new SqlCommand("Insert into linhas (quantidade,descricao,valor) VALUES(@quantidade,@descricao,@valor)", sqlConn);
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", );
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descricao", TextBoxArtigo.Text);
sqlInsertList.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", float.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));

sqlConn.Open();                         
sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
sqlInsert.Transaction = sqlTran;        
sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();             
sqlTran.Commit();
```

Qual é a maneira mais fácil de fazer isso e adaptar o `SQLInsert`?

Comment: Você está tendo algum problema? Parece estar ok, falta só completar um linha.

Comment: Aconselho que em vez de usar três listas, crie somente uma lista tipada com a classe Linha. Será mais fácil percorrer somente um enumerável do que trabalhar com três deles sincronizados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vejo, o problema aqui é que está sendo criado três listas para se operar, em vez de usar somente uma, facilitando abstração da ideia de **Linha**. Primeiro você teria que ter uma classe que represente esse tipo de dado.

```
public class Linha
{
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public float Valor { get; set }
}
```

Usando uma classe concreta você não precisa mais efetuar três loopings, um para cada propriedade da entidade **Linha**.

```
IList<Linha> linhas = new List<Linha>();

for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxListLinhas.Items.Count; i++)
{
    linhas.Add(new Linha
    {
        Quantidade = int.Parse(TextBoxQuantidade.Text.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
        Descricao = TextBoxArtigo.Text.ToString(),
        Valor = float.Parse(TextBoxValor.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)
    });
}
```

Então para inserir todas as linhas o processo fica muito mais simples, com somente um **foreach**.

```
foreach (Linha linha in linhas)
    this.InserirLinha(linha);
}
```

Considere que **InserirLinha** é o seu método atual que serve para tratar somente uma unidade. Modifique o seu código nesse método para que ele trabalhe da seguinte maneira:

```
SqlCommand sqlInsert = new SqlCommand("Insert into linhas (quantidade,descricao,valor) VALUES(@quantidade,@descricao,@valor)", sqlConn);

sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", linha.Quantidade);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descricao", linha.Descricao);
sqlInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", linha.Valor);

sqlConn.Open();                         
sqlTran = sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
sqlInsert.Transaction = sqlTran;        
sqlInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();             
sqlTran.Commit();
```

**OBSERVAÇÕES:**

- Apesar de estar sendo feito um looping, está sempre acessando os mesmos três campos. Não sei se era esse o comportamento que você realmente queria. Se existe várias linhas ou você quer duplicar essa informação.
- Eu usei o tipo **float** para a propriedade **Valor**, mas se for para tratar de um valor monetário o tipo mais adequado para essas operações é o **decimal**.
- Não sei como está o seu método por completo na inserção de uma **Linha**, mas no exemplo que foi passado o **sqlConn** não está sendo fechado. Sempre feche as conexões com operações relacionadas a banco (IO, stream, etc) quando você finalizar a sua ação. Se não quiser usar o método **Close**, geralmente essas classes implementam a interface **IDisposable**, permitindo que dessa maneira você a [Instrução Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx), que já faz esse trabalho por você.

Comment: Peço desculpa pela demora na resposta, mas fiquei com uma pequena dúvida. Esse primeiro ciclo for eu insiro dentro de um método?

Comment: Sim. Nesses casos é sempre bom separar os comportamentos em uma ação coletiva e uma ação única. Se a ação que você vai efetuar pode ser feita para somente uma unidade, separe isso em um método e crie um método que seja um coletivo para sair chamando o método de única unidade.